# Monotouch dialog - Refresh Data from another thread?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a UITabBarController that has a constructor where I dynamically create items for my MT dialog control.  This works fine in that I get mt table rendered correctly.

I have a background thread running from appdelegate checking for new data every 60 seconds.

Whats the best approach for getting new data to the mt.dialog and getting it to refreshed?

thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at InvokeOnMainThread.

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Threading#Developing_Responsive_Applications